# Create multisession ISO image to burn on a remote CD

Tags: data-cd, burning

I need to be able to take a number of files on one machine and generate a .iso image to burn to a *multisession* CD-R that has already had a session written to it.  I can easily create an image for the first session, but I cannot find a way to do so for the second or later sessions.  Currently, the primary means I have of access to the remote system is via `ssh`.  I have `root` on both systems in question.